# Why has my Navigator.push, in drawer no context?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer defined and all worked properly. Somehow it crashed and now I can see my drawer Widget but when I want to add a Navigator push it says:
Undefined name Context. Even when I add

```
BuildContext context;
```

The Button does nothing onTap.

I have implemented my drawer like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: _appBar(),
  drawer: _drawer(),
}    

Widget _drawer() {return Drawer(
  child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 5.0, bottom: 5.0,),
          child: Text(
              "Life",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,)),
        ),

        new ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
            title: new Text("Shops"),
            onTap: () {
              BuildContext context;
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => B()));
            }
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `StatelessWidget` where `context` is not available throughout the class and you need to pass `context` between method.

So the better solution is to convert it to `StatefulWidget` class and you can then use `context` anywhere you want.

See the screenshot how to convert it to `StatefulWidget`. Simply use `alt/option` + `return/enter`.

[image]